# Pre-populate palette colors in Microsoft Office?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, powerpoint, office-interop

My coworkers have very specific colors they use in their Excel and PowerPoint documents, and they came to me hoping for some automation. They often have to go through the annoying task for every new document of re-picking the same three colors off the color selector.

**They have to select the RGB values and then add them to the "Recent Colors" palette for every document.**

[image]

I know there are color themes, but they want to just run a VBA script or easily persist universal settings to have these three colors always pre-loaded.

### Question

Is there a quick way (VBA/feature) to persist universal settings (recent colors) to have these three colors always pre-loaded?

Comment: Interesting question. A good point to start with might be [this](http://excel.tips.net/T002734_Defining_and_Using_Custom_Colors.html). Maybe, you might be able to record in a macro the action described at the end to see what is the object copied from a workbook to the other, then trying to understand if you can build it yourself for automatic customisation and then distribute it as an Add-In.

Comment: Can you set the colors in a blank spreadsheet, then save it as the default template and have them there the next time a document is opened?

Comment: @Matteo NNZ I tried that before I posted. It looks like it didn't record the addition of colors to the palette. It only recorded the colors being applied to the selected cells. So it didn't record the toolbar events :(

Comment: @FreeMan that is a good plan B. Ideally though they'd like to have it applicable to existing documents too.

Comment: I fear that this customization must be done at the level of the XML files containing the RGB codes of the colors in the palette. An idea, hence, might be to find this file into the MS Office Resources directory, and customize it (programmatically or not) to then re-distribute it and let the custom color palette appear in every file opened via the application (old and new).

Comment: Oh man, I hope that is not too dangerous. But I will poke around and explore that.

Comment: If you find the file, then you could create an add-in that would: 1) back-up the file; 2) modify the old one via XML Excel library; 3) let the user choose if wanting to turn the add-in off (in that case, the back-up will replace the old one and the custom one would be destroyed). There might be some more elegant solution but being this is a configuration of Office, it doesn't come anything different to my mind.

Comment: Not quire sure if I see a Resources folder in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14 directory. Is there a specific place I could look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My colleague found a great solution that satisfies our needs perfectly, although it did involve using a color theme so I kind of went outside the scope of my question.

You can export a theme with the desired colors, get the theme's XML in 
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\Theme Colors

and then distribute it to that same folder for everyone else.

Every Office application then has that color theme two clicks away. And this copy procedure can be done with a simple BAT file.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerPoint you can do this ... I don't see an ExtraColors object in the Excel OM though. Maybe there's something similar?

```
Sub AddExtraColors()

    With ActivePresentation.ExtraColors
        .Add RGB(111, 111, 111)
        .Add RGB(222, 222, 222)
        .Add RGB(50, 50, 50)
        ' etc
    End With

End Sub
```

If you can't find a more direct way of doing it, you can always add a shape, set its fill to each of the extra colors you want, one after the other, then delete the shape.  The used colors will remain on the extra colors section of the palette.

Comment: You have to be clever to beat PowerPoint at its own stupidity.  ;-)